# Setting up Pagination with twentytwelve_content_nav

Tags: pagination, theme-twenty-twelve

We are using the twentytwelve theme and I've been trying to fix and set up Pagination for few specific pages. I've set up a Webserver and freshly installed wordpress for this.
I managed to get it to work on the homepage by rewriting the child-theme's home.php to use WP_query instead of query_posts.
This is the relevant code that's working for the homepage:

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'category_name' => 'news' )); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    
     <!-- Start of The Loop-->
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post() ?>
       <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?> 
        <?php endwhile ; ?>
    <?php /* End of The Loop */ ?> 
    <?php /*Pagination here*/ ?> 
    <?php twentytwelve_content_nav ('nav-below'); ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

So far so good. However, any other site is giving me trouble.

I want to use twentytwelve_content_nav to show a link to older posts on the "rezensionen" page  but it does not show any links the way I have tried to do it. My predecessor has used page templates to filter posts so I am trying to write this for the page-rezensionen php file.

Another issue that arose while testing is that somehow, when I open the "rezensionen" page, the URL looks like this: localhost/wordpress/rezensionen-1/
Why could this be?

This is the code for page-rezensionen.php

```
<?php
$the_query = new WP_Query(array( 
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'category_name' => 'rezensionen' )); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    
    <!-- Start of The Loop-->
    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post() ?>
       <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?> 
    <?php endwhile ; ?>
    <?php /* End of The Loop */ ?> 
    <?php /*Pagination here*/ ?> 
    <?php twentytwelve_content_nav ('nav-below'); ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Using previous_posts_link and next_posts_link works if I pass max_num_pages as a parameter, however I'd love to consistently use twentytwelve_content_nav or at least and find out why I can't get it to work. Any help is much appreciated and I apologise if this has already been answered.

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating pages fora each of these categories and not just using the category archives? You should not need to use `new WP_Query` for any of this.

Comment: Ah, the only reason is that was just how it was done before and I still have a lot to learn as you surely noticed.  YES. YES this is the wall I have banged my head against, and have gotten lost finding solutions for issues I don't need to have. 

However, there is a few pages that show posts from multiple categories. For example a page listing all the workers belonging to either of two categories. 
I also wish I'd know why it doesn't work that way but thank you so very much for pointing the right way! Now to do the same for all the other templates which can be replaced by category archives